# Controlling Object That MousePressEvent Returns in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qimage, qlabel, qpushbutton

I have a lot of `qlabels` that display images. When click this qlabels `mousePressEvent` returns which object clicked and I show this images in another `qlabel` with big size.Then I can delete image using `qpushbutton`.If users click more `qlabels` and then click `qpushbutton`, all of images deleted. I want users delete an image per click.So I write a method that delete images but I can't control if user clicks a lot of images and deleting them . How can I do that  ?

```
labels[i].mousePressEvent = functools.partial(self.label_click, source_label = labels[i] ,source_image = pixmap)

def label_click(self, event,source_label=None, source_image=None):

        self.labelDisplayBigImage.setPixmap(source_image)
        self.labelDisplayBigImage.setScaledContents(True)

        if(source_label.picture() == self.labelDisplayBigImage.picture()):
            self.btnCancel.clicked.connect(source_label.clear)
            self.btnCancel.clicked.connect(self.labelDisplayBigImage.clear)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `QListWidget()`. The default `selectionMode()` of `QListWidget` is singleSelection.
Either add the images directly as `QIcon` to the listwidget and set an appropriate iconSize:

```
class MyList(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QListWidget.__init__(self)
        images = ['IMG_1.jpeg', 'IMG_2.jpeg', 'IMG_3.jpeg', 'IMG_4.jpeg', 'IMG_5.jpeg']       
        for i in images:
            icon = QtGui.QIcon(i)
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(icon, i)  
            self.addItem(item)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(150,100))
        self.setSelectionMode(1)            # 1 = SingleSelection, 2 = MultiSelection, not necessary, default mode is singleSelection
        self.setGeometry(200,200,300,500)
```

or add labels containing the images to the listwidget, then an appropriate sizeHint for the item must be given:

```
        for i in images:
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            pm = QtGui.QPixmap(i)
            label.setPixmap(pm.scaled(QtCore.QSize(150,100)))
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(i)
            item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(200,110))
            self.addItem(item)
            self.setItemWidget(item,label)
```

connect to currentItemChanged-signal to get the selected item, (cave: this signal sends 2 items, the current and the previous)

```
        self.currentItemChanged.connect(self.findSel)

    def findSel(self, current, previous):
        print(current.text())
        try:
            print(previous.text())
        except AttributeError:
            print('first selection, no previous item!')
```

Comment: in pyqt4 replace QtWidgets by QtGui